# SFTP with python

Tags: python, bash, ssh, sftp, paramiko

Does anybody know of a methodology to get a remote file from a server using a python script, that will work suitably well for very large files?

I'm currently using Paramiko, and it works quite well, however i'm concerned that the target use case for this will be .bag files of considerable size, potentially around 10 gig. My limited understanding of this is that the downloaded file will be stored in RAM rather than on the drive, until I store it onto the drive.

Or am I loking at optimising a problem that doesn't exist?

Is there a way to save the data as it is being downloaded?

I had thought about just using a bash script, which i suppose would work, but there's a lot of additional functionality that is required. Hence my use of python.

Another option would be to use OS library to simply run SFTP.

I'd appreciate anyones thoughts on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use scp?  Why do you need python at all?

Comment: Or invoke scp from Python (or other automated fashions)

Comment: *"My limited understanding of this is that the downloaded file will be stored in RAM rather than on the drive, until I store it onto the drive"* – Your understanding seems to be wrong.  Paramiko can stream the remote file to local disk. If you have different experience, you have probably done something wrong. We need [mcve].

Comment: @johnGordon, no, no reason. invoking scp using os is a workable option.

Comment: @niko, yeah thats an option.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I wasn't aware that you could do that. What i am doing now is downloading the file into a variable and then saving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem my understanding of Paramiko and SCP / SFTP was flawed.

The default way to do it, does not store it in RAM, and i'd misread code that I'd written last year - we're all guilty of that!

A minimum working example -

```
def DownloadSFTP(self):
    self.sftp.get(self.remotepath, self.localpath)
    self.sftp.close()
```